# Append specific column to a table

Tags: command-line, bash

I have several tables with the following naming style:

```
INSTITUTE_MODEL_SCENARIO_RIVER.txt
```

as examples:

```
wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
wbm_miroc_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_gfdl_rcp4p5_mississippi.txt
matsiro_ipsl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt
```

I want to build an output table grouping the ones having the `INSTITUTE` and `SCENARIO` name in the file name. For that I have the following loop:

```
for institute in wbm matsiro
do
  for scenario in rcp4p5 rcp8p5
  do
    paste "$institute"_*_"$scenario"* > "$hyd_model"_"$scenario".txt
  done
done
```

Unfortunately, while appending the tables to the first one I want to get rid of the three first column (to avoid redundancy).
I know to do that in the command line:

```
paste wbm_gfdl_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt <(cut -f4 wbm_hadgem_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt) <(cut -f4 wbm_miroc_rcp8p5_mississippi.txt) > output.txt
```

But I didn´t succeed to implement that in the `for` loop. Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I'd use an array to capture the relevant files, and use a recursive function to paste each additional file:

```
paste_files() {
    if [[ "$#" -eq 0 ]]; then
        cat -
    else
        paste - <(cut -f4 "$1") | paste_files "${@:1}"
    fi
}

for institute in wbm matsiro; do
    for scenario in rcp4p5 rcp8p5; do
        files=( "$institute"_*_"$scenario"* )
        cat "${files[0]}" | paste_files "${files[@]:1}" > "$hyd_model"_"$scenario".txt
    done
done
```